# Export git repository as (editable) ascii

Tags: git

LibreOffice can save files in `.fodt` which is a nice text format that you can edit and then read back in LibreOffice. The `.fodt` format contains the same information as the binary version.

Is there something similar for `git`?

Maybe something like:

```
git --export-as-ascii /tmp/myrespository.txt
<<edit /tmp/myrespository.txt>>
cd new-place
git --import /tmp/myrespository.txt
```

It should export everything (tags, branches etc) and be as editable as possible.

I understand that checksums will ofcourse be changed if you change the text, and in that case I would love if `git` gives a warning and then just tries computing new checksums.

Comment: Tar it up and run `base64` (or `uuencode`) over it?

Comment: `git format-patch`, edit to your hearts content, and `git am`?

Comment: @Kusalananda That is not edit friendly.

Answer (score 0):

"Export" and "import" of Git can be done through what is called a "bare" repository. `git clone --bare URL PROJECT.git` to create a directory "PROJECT.git" containing just the Git metadata. You can then clone that normally to create a checked-out repo.

If you want that as a single file I would just `tar` it up.

---

Conversely, if you only want the *contents* of a Git repository without the history you can `git checkout-index --all --prefix="../$(basename "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)")-copy/"` to create it as a "PROJECT-copy" sibling directory.